# Whether a word consists of Turkish characters (maybe with numbers) or not?

Tags: java, regex

I have a corpus that has words. I want to do an analyze on them. I accept that they are Turkish characters but some of them are not. So I want to check whether a word does not include a Turkish character or numbers. I mean:

```
hey4    valid
33      valid
kırp    valid
vxz     invalid
ğşiüçö  valid
xwq     invalid
```

How can I check it (with regex or not) fast. I have millions of tokens and I want to drop some of them that I know they are not Turkish because of they includes non Turkish characers.

Comment: I would have thought something like `new Locale("tr").getUnicodeLocaleKeys().contains("x")` would work but `getUnicodeLocaleKeys` returns an empty set for that locale. So it looks like you are going to have to manually track the valid characters.

Comment: So which of those characters are invalid in Turkish? `x` , `w`, and `q`? Any others? `f`? `j`? `z`?

Comment: Valid characters are: a b c ç d e f g ğ h ı i j k l m n o ö p r s ş t u ü v y z and numbers

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can be looking for something like

```
String[] data = {
        "hey4", //     valid
        "33",   //     valid
        "kırp", //     valid
        "vxz",  //     invalid
        "ğşiüçö",//    valid
        "xwq",  //     invalid
};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprsştuüvyz\\d]+",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
// just in case shorter version of regex "[0-9a-pr-yzçğıöşü]+"
for (String s : data)
    System.out.println(s + "\t > " + p.matcher(s).matches());
```

output:

```
hey4    > true
33      > true
kırp    > true
vxz     > false
ğşiüçö  > true
xwq     > false
```